# Is iOs native "Data Protection" available using AIR for iOs?

Tags: ios, encryption, air, adobe, air-native-extension

I want to use Adobe AIR to develop and deploy a custom iOs application in our enterprise - but I have a requirement that I must use iOs native "Data Protection" to encrypt any data stored locally.

I understand that "data protection" is globally enabled on a device by setting a passcode, and that individual applications must then opt-in to use the feature; and typically this "opt-in" is accomplished by invoking the data protection classes in Objective-C.  So my question is, is it possible for an AIR-for-iOs app to use native data protection, given that it's developed in a different language (Flex / ActionScript in my case), and I have no access to the Objective-C code?

My first guess is that there's possibly an app-level flag I can set (either within AIR development or after generating the .ipa file), that will automatically apply data protection to any local data.  That would be nice.

My second guess is that I could develop and call an AIR Native Extension whose sole function is to encrypt and decrypt, using the native data protection classes.  This would be less preferable, as I'm not an Objective-C / XCode developer.

I am familiar with AIR's own encryption APIs; but iOS-native data protection is the only currently accepted encryption method in our enterprise.  So if I can't get this to work, I'll have to abandon AIR for iOs development.